# Regex to find numbers and letters

Tags: regex

I would find validate the following syntax using regex from zero to 99, then "x", then again 0 to 99.

Example:

```
03x10
01x08 
99x99
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget to include start `^` and end `$` anchors in your regex.

```
^\d{2}x\d{2}$
```

- `\d{2}` will match exactly two digits.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hX4tN8/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

From 0 to 99

```
^[0-9][1-9]?x[0-9][1-9]?$
```

To allow from 00 to 99:

```
 ^[0-9][0-9]?x[0-9][0-9]?$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 /[0-9]{2}x[0-9]{2}/
```

should do the trick...